# What does "beat free" (or "can't beat free") mean?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning, expressions

> *The Impossible Book*
>
> – Hey, let’s go for a walk or something!
>
> – Oh, I’m kind of busy here…
>
> – Busy bee as always. What are you doing? Reading again? Let me see
>   the title.
>
> – It’s a bit silly, actually. You’re gonna laugh. The title is [“It is
>   impossible to teach you a foreign language”](https://docviewer.yandex.ru/?url=ya-disk-public%3A%2F%2FskjQN1FZ%2FgfmRTMyG80g1zDJqQb4JLiRLoe5MdlBBr0%3D&name=Language%20Tai-chi%2C%20book.pdf&c=549ed82577b4).
>
> – So? Like I didn’t know. I always knew there was no way I could be
>   taught a foreign language.
>
> – That’s exactly the point the author makes. His whole argument is
>   that you must teach yourself.  You can learn it only yourself, from
>   within; no one can teach you, from without.  No teacher, no professor,
>   no one.
>
> – Well, hmm… maybe, it’s not as stupid as the title sounds.
>
> – No, it’s not. It’s pretty funny but also smart at the same time. I
>   think you’d like it.
>
> – I’m suspicious. The guy probably sells you some snake oil in the
>   end. One of those scam artists.
>
> – Nothing of the kind. You just are being cynical. You’ve got to trust
>   people a little more.
>
> – If you say so, but I’m intrigued. Maybe, I can borrow the book from
>   you sometime.
>
> – Sure. When I’m done with it. By the way, you can download it from
>   the Web. For free.
>
> – Really? Maybe, I’ll do that. **You can’t beat free**…

So, what does it mean? When is it used?

What is the origin of this expression?

Comment: "You can learn it only yourself, from within; no one can teach you, from without." Your actual question aside, the grammar of this sentence bothers me. Where did you find this text?

Comment: It is one of the latest dialogues from "matrix language course" for American English (which I used to learn). Read the *impossible book* to learn more about what the "matrix language course" is. The book is free (I posted the link).

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to warn you of the dubious grammar that appears in that extract. Fortunately, the book itself doesn't seem plagued by the same problem.

Comment: @Stephan That's perfectly fine grammar (well the punctuation could be argued about). If it's the `without` that bothers you check out [points 9/10](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/without)

Comment: @blgt: I'll admit I've never encountered such usage of "without". Regardless, I would not expect to hear a construction like "you can learn it only yourself" from anyone other than a foreign student or perhaps a poet.

Comment: It sounds like standard "guru" or "sensei" jargon to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*You can't beat* is an idiom meaning "There is nothing better than"; it derives from the use of *beat* in the sense *defeat, prove superior to*.

> You can't beat bacon and eggs for breakfast.
>   Whatever you think of the Beatles, you can't beat the Stones for longevity.

In this case, your interlocutor means "There is no better price than free".

Comment: You can't beat StoneyB; he's too quick.

Comment: Side note... you _can_ beat eggs :P

Answer (score 13):

It is using beat [definition 12 here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beat).

Beat can mean to win, as in a sporting competition.  One team beats another.  In this case, the competing entities are monetary prices.  The book costs nothing (it is free), and with prices you can't win against a price of nothing, so you "can't beat free."